# Problem of Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> If $a \gt 0$, show that $$a^{x} \le 1 + (a-1)x ; \quad 0 \le x \le 1.$$

Comment: Lookup [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality). If you need to rediscover / independently prove that, then you should post more context.

Comment: post what you have tried when you ask a question on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT** One way is to consider
$$
f(x) = a^x + (1-a)x
$$
and show that $f(x) \le 1$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Another is to look at
$$
(1+x)^k = 1 + kx + \ldots
$$
e.g. via continuous interpretation of the Binomial theorem.